# how to find centre of a plane found in a hit test ARKit SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

In an image detection app, the image is recognised, then an opaque overlay plane is created so when the user taps on the screen a hit test finds the overlay plane, and a new object can be created. But I want to position the object exactly at the centre of the underlying image. How can I get it to be always at the centre of the image / plane, and to have the same orientation. Can this be got from a hit test result? Thanks for any advice!

```
@objc func handleScreenTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  let tappedSceneView = sender.view as! ARSCNView
  let tapLocation = sender.location(in: tappedSceneView)

  let planeIntersections = tappedSceneView.hitTest(tapLocation, types: [.estimatedHorizontalPlane, .estimatedVerticalPlane])
  if !planeIntersections.isEmpty {
    addSceneAtPositionOnPlane(hitTestResult: planeIntersections.first!)
}

func addSceneAtPositionOnPlane(hitTestResult: ARHitTestResult) {

  let transform = hitTestResult.worldTransform
  let positionColumn = transform.columns.3
  let initialPosition = SCNVector3(positionColumn.x,
                                 positionColumn.y,
                                 positionColumn.z)

   let node = self.createScene(for: initialPosition)
   sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
}

func createScene(for position: SCNVector3) -> SCNNode {

  let box = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 0.1, //x
                                    height: 0.1, //y
                                    length: 0.1, //z
                                    chamferRadius: 0))

  box.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
  box.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
  box.opacity = 0.8

  box.position = position        
  return box
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you already added a SCNNode to render a plane on top of the detected image, then you could just use the SceneKit hitTest method that returns a SceneKit node vs. trying to hit test against ARKit geometry.

Once you have the plane you added to the scene you can just add your new geometry as a child of that node.

Here is an example where once the image is detected a plane is drawn on top of it, then when the user clicks on the plane a box is added as a child, the box will then follow the tracked image around and have the correct position and orientation.

```swift
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sceneView.delegate = self

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTap))
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
  }

  @objc func onTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)

    guard let hit = sceneView.hitTest(point, options: nil).first else {
      return
    }

    let box = SCNBox(width: 0.02, height: 0.02, length: 0.02, chamferRadius: 0)
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: box)
    node.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0.01)
    box.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    hit.node.addChildNode(node)
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    guard let images = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "ARTest", bundle: nil) else {
      return
    }

    configuration.detectionImages = images
    configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 1
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
  }

  func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else {
      return
    }

    let size = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -Float.pi / 2
    planeNode.opacity = 0.9
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)
  }

  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    sceneView.session.pause()
  }

}
```

Comment: hi Mark - will pick up the point on the plane where the user taps or the exact centre of the plane / image underneath it?

Comment: This example will add the box at the center of the plane. You need to make sure you have an accurate width/height set on the image in your AR Resource group.

Comment: I had to add self.sceneView.session.setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: imageAnchor.transform) after addChildNode in renderer didAdd node. Or the box is created at origin at start of AR session

Comment: Is it possible to get the dimensions of the plane from the hitTest?